# jFrog builds - how to not delete production artifact

Tags: devops, artifactory

I want to be able to ensure that in a JFrog release repo which houses only production builds, the current prod build is NOT deleted in any circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Permission Targets](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions) to granularly set access to different repositories and remove write access.

Another option to create immutable bundles of artifacts is to use JFrog [Distribution](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Distribution) and [create Release Bundles](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Distributing+Release+Bundles)
Distribution allows to sign and release immutable sets of artifacts to different (or same) artifactory instance.

Lastly, you can use the [Build Promotion](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BuildPromotion) to add properties to release artifacts or move them to specific repositories; this will allow us to leverage a [User Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/User+Plugins) such as the one we provide: [restrictOverwrite](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/storage/restrictOverwrite).

The user plugin will be able to change the response regardless of permissions according to the logic defined. The example will need to be adapted, but the syntax and general idea work. The plugin uses endpoints: `beforeCreate`, `beforeCopy`, and `beforeMove` as it is meant to prevent overwrites, but you may use the `beforeDelete` endpoint mentioned in the docs linked before.